# How do I use update(..., {upsert: true}) with sharded collections?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection whose documents are structured like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("..."),
    shardKey: 12345,
    name: "Some User"
}
```

The collection is sharded on `shardKey`.

If I perform a `findAndModify`:

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {shardKey: 67890},
    update: {$set: {shardKey: 67890, name: "Hello, World!"}},
    upsert: true
});
```

If a record exists with `shardKey` equal to `67890`, then the name will be set to `"Hello, World!"`. If the record *doesn't* exist, a new one will be created with `shardKey: 67890` and `name: "Hello, World!"`

Fine. That's expected.

However, if I do the same thing using `update(...)` instead:

```
db.collection.update(
    {shardKey: 67890},
    {$set: {shardKey: 67890, name: "Hello, World!"}},
    {upsert: true}
);
```

Then MongoDB complains:

```
Can't modify shard key's value. field: shardKey: 67890
```

Even if the record doesn't exist yet.

1. I would expect that upserting using `update(...)` when no record already exists wouldn't be a problem. Is this a bug?
2. Why does `findAndModify` handle this fine? Internally, does it only update fields that have changed, thus omiting `shardKey` when the record is found?
3. Is there another solution, besides `findAndModify(...)` that doesn't involve making two trips to the database (one to `find` the record if it's already there, and then one more to `insert` or `update` depending on the result)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in MongoDB 2.4.0.  Please refer this [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9074).  It has been fixed (in development release 2.5.4) and will be available in the next production version of MongoDB i.e., 2.6.0. The release candidate 2.6.0-rc1 is available now and you can use that, if that's acceptable in your situation.